# Oracle EBS: Get profile values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I was working with Oracle R12 application.Can anybody suggest some queries to identify the `Profile names and Profile values` related to a particular product/item selected??

I tried using

```
SELECT *
FROM fnd_profile_options_vl po,
fnd_profile_option_values pov,
fnd_user usr,
fnd_application app,
fnd_responsibility rsp,
fnd_nodes svr,
hr_operating_units org
WHERE 1 = 1
AND pov.application_id = po.application_id
AND pov.profile_option_id = po.profile_option_id
AND usr.user_id(+) = pov.level_value
AND rsp.application_id(+) = pov.level_value_application_id
AND rsp.responsibility_id(+) = pov.level_value
AND app.application_id(+) = pov.level_value
AND svr.node_id(+) = pov.level_value
AND org.organization_id(+) = pov.level_value
```

It will return all profile values. But how can I identify the profile value of an item/product I selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my post:http://blog.csdn.net/pan_tian/article/details/7652968

```
1.    List E-Business Suite Profile Option Values For All Levels
2.    How to Search all of the Profile Options for a Specific Value
3.    How To Find All Users With A Particular Profile Option Set
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the profile of actual Oracle product itself, or are you querying these values from an actual table from your implementation? If it is a particular implementation, could you state what columns you are working with?

Please verify.

Comment: I was trying to join these tables.FND_PROFILE_OPTIONS , FND_PROFILE_OPTIONS_TL,FND_PROFILE_OPTION_VALUES. But how can I relate this with a product/item?I just need the profile values for any item i selected.

Comment: Is there any connection between products/items with profile options??

Answer (score 0):

Profile Options have several things to search on:
- the level (site, responsibility, ...)
- their technical name (ABCDEFGH)
- their user name (setting for ...)

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL for Blitz Report [FND Profile Option Values](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-profile-option-values/) should do the trick. You'll find additional where-clauses for different query scenarios e.g. by profile option value on that report's page as well.

The SQL also shows the visible profile option values translated through custom function [xxen_util.display_profile_option_value()](https://www.enginatics.com/xxen_util/true).

```
select
fav0.application_name,
fpo.user_profile_option_name,
decode(fpov.level_id,10001,'Site',10002,'Application', 10003,'Responsibility', 10004,'User', 10005,'Server',10006,'Operating Unit',
10007,decode(to_char(fpov.level_value2),'-1','Responsibility',decode(to_char(fpov.level_value),'-1','Server','Server+Resp'))
) level_,
decode(fpov.level_id,10001,null,10002,fav.application_name,10003,frv.responsibility_name,10004,fu.user_name||nvl2(nvl(fu.description,fu.email_address),': '||nvl(fu.description,fu.email_address),null),10005,fn.node_name,10006,haou.name,
10007,decode(to_char(fpov.level_value2),'-1',frv.responsibility_name,decode(to_char(fpov.level_value),'-1',fn.node_name,fn.node_name||' - '||frv.responsibility_name))
) level_name,
xxen_util.display_profile_option_value(fpo.application_id,fpo.profile_option_id,fpov.profile_option_value) profile_option_value,
fpov.last_update_date,
fu2.user_name||nvl2(nvl(fu2.description,fu2.email_address),': '||nvl(fu2.description,fu2.email_address),null) last_updated_by,
fpov.profile_option_value system_profile_option_value,
fpo.profile_option_name system_profile_option_name,
fpo.profile_option_id,
fpov.level_value,
fpov.level_value2
from
fnd_application_vl fav0,
fnd_profile_options_vl fpo,
fnd_profile_option_values fpov,
fnd_responsibility_vl frv,
fnd_user fu,
fnd_application_vl fav,
fnd_user fu2,
hr_all_organization_units haou,
fnd_nodes fn
where
fav0.application_name=:application_name and
1=1 and
fav0.application_id=fpo.application_id and
fpo.profile_option_id=fpov.profile_option_id and
fpo.application_id=fpov.application_id and
decode(fpov.level_id,10002,fpov.level_value)=fav.application_id(+) and
case when fpov.level_id in (10003,10007) then fpov.level_value end=frv.responsibility_id(+) and
case when fpov.level_id in (10003,10007) then fpov.level_value_application_id end=frv.application_id(+) and
decode(fpov.level_id,10004,fpov.level_value)=fu.user_id(+) and
decode(fpov.level_id,10005,fpov.level_value,10007,fpov.level_value2)=fn.node_id(+) and
decode(fpov.level_id,10006,fpov.level_value)=haou.organization_id(+) and
fpov.last_updated_by=fu2.user_id
order by
fpo.user_profile_option_name,
fpov.level_id,
decode(fpov.level_id,10001,null,10002,fav.application_name, 10003,frv.responsibility_name, 10004,fu.user_name||nvl2(nvl(fu.description,fu.email_address),': '||nvl(fu.description,fu.email_address),null), 10005,fn.node_name,10006,haou.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT fpo.profile_option_name SHORT_NAME,
         fpot.user_profile_option_name NAME,
         DECODE (fpov.level_id,
                 10001, 'Site',
                 10002, 'Application',
                 10003, 'Responsibility',
                 10004, 'User',
                 10005, 'Server',
                 'UnDef')
            LEVEL_SET,
         DECODE (TO_CHAR (fpov.level_id),
                 '10001', '',
                 '10002', fap.application_short_name,
                 '10003', frsp.responsibility_key,
                 '10005', fnod.node_name,
                 '10006', hou.name,
                 '10004', fu.user_name,
                 'UnDef')
            "CONTEXT",
         fpov.profile_option_value VALUE
    FROM fnd_profile_options fpo,
         fnd_profile_option_values fpov,
         fnd_profile_options_tl fpot,
         fnd_user fu,
         fnd_application fap,
         fnd_responsibility frsp,
         fnd_nodes fnod,
         hr_operating_units hou
   WHERE     fpo.profile_option_id = fpov.profile_option_id(+)
         AND fpo.profile_option_name = fpot.profile_option_name
         AND fu.user_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND frsp.application_id(+) = fpov.level_value_application_id
         AND frsp.responsibility_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fap.application_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fnod.node_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND hou.organization_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fpot.user_profile_option_name IN ('&User_Profile_Option_Name')
ORDER BY short_name;

      SELECT fpo.profile_option_name SHORT_NAME,
         fpot.user_profile_option_name NAME,
         DECODE (fpov.level_id,
                 10001, 'Site',
                 10002, 'Application',
                 10003, 'Responsibility',
                 10004, 'User',
                 10005, 'Server',
                 'UnDef')
            LEVEL_SET,
         DECODE (TO_CHAR (fpov.level_id),
                 '10001', '',
                 '10002', fap.application_short_name,
                 '10003', frsp.responsibility_key,
                 '10005', fnod.node_name,
                 '10006', hou.name,
                 '10004', fu.user_name,
                 'UnDef')
            "CONTEXT",
         fpov.profile_option_value VALUE
    FROM fnd_profile_options fpo,
         fnd_profile_option_values fpov,
         fnd_profile_options_tl fpot,
         fnd_user fu,
         fnd_application fap,
         fnd_responsibility frsp,
         fnd_nodes fnod,
         hr_operating_units hou
   WHERE     fpo.profile_option_id = fpov.profile_option_id(+)
         AND fpo.profile_option_name = fpot.profile_option_name
         AND fu.user_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND frsp.application_id(+) = fpov.level_value_application_id
         AND frsp.responsibility_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fap.application_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fnod.node_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND hou.organization_id(+) = fpov.level_value
         AND fpot.user_profile_option_name IN ('&User_Profile_Option_Name')
ORDER BY short_name;

enter code here
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)